# Matching a word as a group in regular expressions

Tags: regex

**Input text:**

```
## (Chat room 1) Received message from client 1: Nice to meet you!
(CR 1) RM 1: Nice to meet you!
(CR 1) SM 1: Nice to meet you!
## (Client 1) Received message from client 1: Nice to meet you!
(CL 1) RM 1: Nice to meet you!
(CR 0) SM 3: Nice to meet you!
## (Client 3) Received message from client 3: Nice to meet you!
(CL 3) RM 3: Nice to meet you!
```

**Pattern:**

```
(##[^\n]*\n)|(\((CR|CL) \d+\)) ((RM|SM) [0-9]:)|[a-zA-Z|!]*
```

My main problem is with matching Nice to meet you as a group and not individual words like seen below:

[image: Problem visual output]

My initial solution was changing `[a-zA-Z|!]*` to `[a-zA-Z|\s|!]*` but it then captures all the space in the given trace text.

Comment: FYI, groups don't use `|`, unless you want to include `|` as a character you want to match. ex. `[a-zA-Z\s!]*`

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(##[^\n]*\n)|(\((CR|CL) \d+\)) ((RM|SM) [0-9]:)|([a-zA-Z]+!?(?: [a-zA-Z]*!?)*)` https://regex101.com/r/dVgxB7/1 You can add it to the character class or optionally match it after it.

Comment: @iPhoenix I simply removed the '|' and it seems to capture like i want

Comment: Henry, I assume you know that you should disregard requests that you select a particular answer. I see one was made less than 10 minutes after you posted the question. More generally, quick selections can discourage other answers or result in errors in the selected answer being undetected (though that will not happen here). Also, recognize that other members may still be working on answers. Most wait a minimum of a couple of hours before making a selection; some wait much longer.  Just don't forget to select the answer you find most helpful, provided at least one was useful.

Comment: You have not stated your question. From what you have written I cannot tell what is to be done if, for example, an entire line were `"(CR 1) RM 1:"` or the entire string were `"## (Chat room 1)"`. That line and string would be matched by your regex. Is that intended?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for bringing this to my notice

Comment: @CarySwoveland  I don't seem to quite picture what exactly you mean. My intended question was to match "Nice to meet you!" as a group instead of just individual words as depicted in the picture above

Comment: Your regex (which is inadequate in the respect you mention) consists of an alternation with three components. Think of it as `a|b|c`. Right now it correctly matches `a` and `b`. Let's say `c` is changed so that it matches `Nice to meet you!` in `(CR 1) RM 1: Nice to meet you!`. There is no requirement, however, that `c` only matches `Nice to meet you!` when the previous part of that line matches `b`. That is, it will match `Nice to meet you!` in `Looks like rain: Nice to meet you!`. Similarly, the matching of `a` and  `b` are treated independently...

Comment: ...That's why you need to state your question. Do you wish to match any element of the alternation regardless of whether the others match or do you wish to match each component (successively) only if all three match? Also, in my previous comment I asked "Is that intended?" Is it?

Comment: Thank you for your patience and insights but my initial question was to match nice to meet you ! as a group this is as simply as I can put it. The previous made if you take a look at the regex in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want another capture group, you can capture matching what is in the character class and repeat that 1+ times optionally followed by a space and again repeating the character class.

If you use `[a-zA-Z!]` you might possibly also match only multiple exclamation marks `!!!`

If you don't want to match that as a separate word, you can optionally match a single `!` afterwards `[a-zA-Z]+!?` so you would only match words that could possibly end with an exclamation mark.

```
(##[^\n]*\n)|(\((CR|CL) \d+\)) ((RM|SM) [0-9]:)|([a-zA-Z]+!?(?: [a-zA-Z]*!?)*)
```

The updated part `([a-zA-Z]+!?(?: [a-zA-Z]*!?)*)` matches:

- `(` Capture **group 6** (group 6 in the whole pattern)

  - `[a-zA-Z]+!?` Match 1+ times a-zA-Z and optional `!`
  - `(?:`

    - `[a-zA-Z]*!?` Match a space, char a-zA-Z and optional `!`
  - `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times to match more words
- `)` Close capture group 6

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dVgxB7/1)

---

Matching all chars in the character class, but not matching spaces only:

```
(##[^\n]*\n)|(\((CR|CL) \d+\)) ((RM|SM) [0-9]:)|([a-zA-Z!]+(?: [a-zA-Z!]*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zyx1Fj/1)

Comment: I am a bit confuse with the use of ?  and i like your logical reasoning in approaching the solution

Comment: @HenryTirla I have added a breakdown of the added part. `!?` means match a `!` and make it optional using `?`

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing something like this:

```
(##[^\n]*\n)|(\((CR|CL) \d+\)) ((RM|SM) [0-9]:)([a-zA-Z!\s]*)
```

This merges the part of the regex capturing the ex. `(CR 0) SM 3` and the part of the regex capturing the stuff following it by removing the `|` between them.

This means that it only captures the spaces if it is preceded by the `(CR 0) SM 3` text.